# How to display a separate webpage for tablet devices than mobile devices

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, asp-classic, tablet

So long story short, we've got a mobile project for all our mobile users i.e. Mobile & Tablets but we're looking at implementing a way to show a homepage based on if you're visiting from a mobile or from a tablet.

Is there anyway to do this on an application level as we've got the mobile redirect setup in IIS already which picks up if the user is on a mobile device in general and redirects.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this simple js solution can help you: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex9/info3.htm

Comment: How does this apply to displaying a new partial view/homepage file rather than suggesting we link them across to a separate solution just for tablets?

Comment: This solution is based on the case you have separeted sites for desktop and mobile clients, like "yoursite.com" and "m.yoursite.com", that is a common practice. If you have separate pages or parts of pages, a server side code must be more apropriate.

Comment: Rather than trying to detect the device and sending to a different page, make your page dynamic enough so that it renders correctly regardless of the screen size.  Device detection is fraught with problems